# What is the probability that in the first cycle you will lose half of the signals that reached the system?

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

I have the next question:
 
A communication system consists of two parts, component and communication line. The component stores all signals that are coming from a particular source, and the line of communication transmits the signals to the receiver. The system works in one-second cycles. The number of signals coming from the source to the component every second is a Poisson process with a parameter *$\lambda $*. The maximum number of signals that can be stored in a component is an integer constant *b*, and at the end of every second, the system sends the signals stored in the component to the receiver through the communication line. The maximum amount of signals that can be sent per second through the communication line is an integer constant *c* ($0<c<b$). If more the *b* signals come so the remainder is lost (and not stored in the component), and *c* is the maximum number of signals that can be sent through the line of communication. Assume that in the initial state the system is empty.

a. Find the probability function of:
  
 1. The number of signals stored at the end of the first cycle before sending.
2. The number of signals stored at the end of the first cycle after sending.

b.What is the probability that in the first cycle you will lose half of the signals that reached the system? An answer can be given as a series.

My solution for **a**:
The distribution of the number of signals is Poissonic as given and therefore in one cycle k=1 and we will get the number of signals that will come is: $\lambda e^{-\lambda }$. I marked this number as *i*.
For the number of signals in storage before sending the probability function is:
$B=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\lambda e^{-\lambda }-b & b<i\\ 
 \lambda e^{-\lambda }& b>i
\end{matrix}\right.$

For the number of signals in storage after sending:
$A=\left\{\begin{matrix}
B-c & c<B\\ 
0& c>B
\end{matrix}\right.$

But I do not know how to use the result of question a to solve the question b. Can anyone help me, please? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: you are wrong in solution for "a" in both questions:
1. probability of having $i > b$ before sending should be $0$, because container can't store more than $b$. Also your formulas don't depend on $i$
2. probability can't be $B - c$ as this is a count, that can go beyond $1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a.1

let $X$ be the number of signals prior to the sending. Let $Y$ be number of signals came ($X$ can't go beyond limit $b$, while $Y$ can).

Then,

$$\begin{equation*}
  p_X(m) = \begin{cases}
    e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^m}{m!} & m < b \\
    p\left(Y \ge b\right) = 1 - p\left(Y < b\right) = 1 - \sum_{k=0}^{b-1} \textbf{<can you finish here>} & m = b
  \end{cases} 
  \end{equation*}$$

a.2

Let $Z$ be the number of signals after sending. There are cases: if $X \le c$ than $Z=0$, otherwise $Z = X - c$, however need carefully look at one more corner case when $X = b$:

$$\begin{equation*}
  p_Z(m) = \begin{cases}
    e^{-\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^c \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} & m = 0\\
    p_X(m+c) = \textbf{<can you finish here>} & 0 < m < b - c\\
    p_X(b) = \textbf{<can you finish here>} & m = b - c
  \end{cases} 
  \end{equation*}$$

b
The system loses only signals coming out of the limit $b$. Note that signals from $c + 1$ to $b$ are not lost, and will be eventually sent the following seconds. Thus, the event that in the first cycle you will lose half of the signals that reached the system is the same event as receiving at least $2b$ signals and probability of that is $P_x(m > 2b)$, can you complete from here?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. But I can't understand why at $P_{x}(m)$ when m=b the distribution is the probability function of Y when Y>b?

Comment: Because regardless how many signals you receive that are beyond b, they’ll be clipped to b, because the container limit is b

Comment: I am sorry for bothering you but I can't understand something. If at $P_{x}$ the limit is b, why do we calculate $P(Y\geq b)$ and not $P(Y\leq  b)$

Comment: @violettagold. let me elaborate but prior to that let's clarify one confusing part about the problem statement. If limit b reached and new signals coming. Are they 1. still stored till the end of the second and later lost or 2. they are lost instantly, because container limit is b, and they don't fit. My solution is for "2" interpretation, and intuitively I think that makes more sense, but can you confirm we are aligned on that understanding?

Comment: Yes, I understand.

Comment: then, 
if b signals come, you'll get b at the end

if b+1 signals come, you'll get b at the end

if b+2 signals come, you'll get b at the end.

etc.

thus, we sum up probabilities of b, b+1, b+2. They all contribute to final probability to get b at the end

Comment: Right. I got that.

Comment: Again, sorry for disturbing you, I just want to be sure that I got it right. For $P_{x}(m)$ when $m=b$ the distribution of the probability function is $1-e^{-\lambda }\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{b-1} \frac{\lambda ^{k}}{k!}$. 
 Also, can you explain please me your solution for a.2? If we look at $X=b$ how could $m=0$?

Comment: your formula looks correct. For a.2 see that for $m=0$ we sum up till $c$, not $b$ in $e^{-\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^c \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$. Thus, we can get $0$ when $X=b$ only in case when $c=b$

Comment: I am confused by something, is m stands for the number of signals before sending at $P_{z}(m)$  ?

Comment: @violettagold, see in the solution "Let  be the number of signals after sending" -> thus $P_z(m)$ means probability of getting $m$ signals after sending

Comment: Ok, got is. Thank you very much for the patience and all the help :)